# c++ constant function in class

Tags: c++, function, oop, constants

Hello can someone please explain what does the `const` means in front of function declaration like so :

```
const void function(parameters);
```

I know, it means you can't modify what it returns, but how are we able to modify, what it returns? Thanks for any kind of reply.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't `constexpr void function(parameters);`? I've never seen such construct and I've some doubts if it makes sense (not to mention whether the compiler accepts this).

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `const void` return type.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes it makes no sense, but it makes no sense to disallow it either.

Comment: OK. [g++ -std=C++17 -pedantic](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e229908bf7c78b) seems to accept it (and even doesn't complain). But return type `const void` still doesn't make sense to me. (`void` is `void`.)

Comment: @Scheff It's allowed because `const void*` is actually a thing. Yeah legacy code

Comment: @NathanOliver I wasn't much afraid of the grammar but assumed at least a complaint by semantic check. However even `g++ -Wall` didn't find it worth a complaint...

Comment: `<source>:1:1: warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]
` - live- https://godbolt.org/z/dP656j1ec

Comment: @Scheff ^ that.  C++ ignores top level const on return types so the OP basically has `void function(parameters);`

Comment: @RicharCritten seems like gcc does not agree with itself: https://godbolt.org/z/rob5aoadx. Is this a gcc bug then?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 This is probably just such case, nobody cared to check for (as it simply doesn't make sense), and then it slipped through and makes the nearly perfect application broken a bit. (Development would be much easier if there weren't users...) :-)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 add `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and you get both the warning and the assert fail; I would say say bug in a corner-case.

Comment: From the `decltype` experiment it looks like the declared types are different, because the declarations are different ... yet it also seems that the actual types are the same (because the difference in declarations has no effect). I wonder if there might be other examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means exactly nothing. The function does not return anything so the `const` modifier modifies nothing.

Comment: but see RichardCrittens comment above with a link to gcc claiming it would ignore the `const`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 follow up - the _"big 3"_ all agree that the types are different https://godbolt.org/z/dbWEnejob

Comment: With regards to name mangling or behaviour?

Comment: @RichardCritten interesting. I don't think its too obscure to encounter a case where it does make a difference whether it is ignored or not. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/oebWjYv5Y (well, `const T` return is a little obscure and the recommendation to use it is obsolete, but still)

Answer (score 0):

To answer what *probably* was asked, you can return object, pointer or reference. If you don't want these to be modified by caller, then you use `const`.

I.e. something like that:

```
char *bar() {
  static char buf[100];
  ... some code ...
  return buf;
}

const char *foo() {
  static char buf[100];
  ... some code ...
  return buf;
}

b = bar();
*b = 'A'; // OK
f = foo();
*f = 'A'; // Error
```

Same goes with references and objects. Objects can be useful to declare `const` even by value because some objects can share common data even when copied.

BTW: This is not constant functions, but functions returning constant value. Constant functions is completely different thing.